# UCanAccess error: user lacks privilege or object not found: WHERE

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am currently trying to update a record using Java Netbeans into a MS Access Database and i keep on getting the following error:

```
ERROR: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: WHERE
```

The following is my code:

```
public void Edit(Customer a, int id) {     
    con = DBConnect();

    String sql = "Update Customer set CName =?,CAge =?,CPhone =?,CAddress =?, CGender =?, WHERE [ID] =" + id + "";


    try {
        s = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        s.setString(1, a.getName());
        s.setString(2, a.getAge());
        s.setString(3, a.getContact());
        s.setString(4, a.getAddress());
        s.setString(5, a.getGender());

        s.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Customer profile Updated");       

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: something tells me that you didn't grant proper privileges for user that connects to the database

Comment: oh, how do i access to privileges for user that connects to the database? I'm sorry because i'm really new to database and java as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the comma immediately before the WHERE keyword. You need to remove it. That is, change

```
CGender =?, WHERE
```

to

```
CGender =? WHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you often mistype the query. Double check the syntax of the query. It will solve the error surely.